# Redisson acquires new connection for each request

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am currently testing reddison client for redis. For a simple RMap set and get I am getting a time of 10ms. When comparing it to jedis, jedis only takes 2 ms to complete set and get. My reddison test code is below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Config config = new Config();
config.useSentinelServers().setCheckSentinelsList(false).setMasterName("mymaster")
        .addSentinelAddress("redis://localhost:26379").setPassword("zzz");

RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
RMap<String, String> map = redisson.getMap("myMap");
while (true) {
    System.out.println("ENTER");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    try {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        map.put("test", s);
        System.out.println("OUTPUT:::" + map.get("test"));
        System.out.println(Duration.between(start, LocalDateTime.now()).toMillis());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

After checking debug logs I found out that reddison acquires a connection every time before doing a put or get( LOG:: acquired connection for command ). Is there a way to keep redisson client use the same connection for all requests and avoid this cost?

Answer (score 1):

Redisson uses connection pool. **Never creates new connection** per operation. First operation with data may require default codec to do initialization. Since 3.16.1 version default data codec warmup process has been added.

Comment: Every time I do a set or get request, in the debug logs it says acquired connection for command which is causing the 10ms latency I think. How can I avoid this? I have already tried 3.16.1

Comment: It gets it from connection pool. You can check source code.